# -webkit-column-count gives with unexpected results

Tags: html, css, webkit, multiple-columns

So I'm using the -webkit-column-count on a p tag which contains multiple span tags. 
Each span contains ONE letter.

In between the span tags, there is a another span which is drag able so the user can drag and drop it wherever he wants to.

The problem starts when the user drop it on the edge of the p tag.

When it happens, the image gets cut out of the frame.

Can't tell why..

The one thing I see is when I remove the z-index from the dragable span it suddenly works good but the second dragable span get off it's position.

Please look at the example of [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q2q7W/3/)

This is my HTML code:

```
<div>
<p class="two_columns">
<span class="ui-draggable">&nbsp;</span>
Lorem ipsum sit amet, consectetur adipiscing sdfsdf consectetur adipiscing sdfsdf 
consectetur adipiscing sdfsdf elit. Praesent rhoncus tellus purus
<span class="ui-draggable">&nbsp;</span>, utfacilisis ipsum posu ere eget. Cras
susciconsectetur adipiscing sdfsdf consectetur adipiscing sdfsdfdio.</p>
</div>
```

And this is my css:

```
div {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 20px auto;
}

p {
    overflow: visible !important;
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
}

.ui-draggable {
    text-indent: -9999px;
    display: inline !important;
    z-index: 100;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0;
}
.ui-draggable::after {
   position: absolute;
content: '';
width: 24px;
height: 30px;
background: url("https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQLBPLYyDEATQHLjBBl5UD-pSD9PI5rv_EAElcSPT7HGk2LKSKeAVkgCa-o") no-repeat;
cursor: pointer;
left: -10px;
top: -20px;
background-size: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an absolutely positioned :after pseudo on you ui-draggable class. This is going to make the image float above everything (that is what absolute positioning does, float above the existing layout).

One way to fix that is to add a margin to the ui-draggable class to make space for the icon:

`margin: 0 15px 0 5px;`

I also worry about why you are using so many spans when most of them have no styling on them at all. Look at removing some of the excess if you can. The fewer HTML elements you have the easier it usually is to make things behave themselves.

Comment: Sorry but it's not solving my problem since I want the draggable span to remain on the letter it's currently on.
If I add margin then the draggable span will change it's position.
And regarding your worries about the multiple spans - Don't be :)